# Различие интерпретации препроцессора в различных компиляторах?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, препроцессор

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, истоки которой так и не смог пока определить.
Дело в том, что компилятор GCC позволяет делать следующее:

```
#define RND_SEED ((int)(__TIME__[6]) * (int)(__TIME__[7]))
#define X_DIM RND_SEED%(2-1+1)+1
#define Y_DIM RND_SEED%(5-3+1)+3

...

int my_2D_array[Y_DIM][X_DIM];
```

Т.е вычисление зерна(RND_SEED) и зависимых от него переменных препроцессора определяются константными значениями.

В MSVC же этот код не выполнится, т.к X_DIM и Y_DIM не будут определены константами => выделить таким образом память не удастся.

В чем тут дело?

Comment: А если попросить и GCC и студию выдать файл после препроцессора и сравнить? У меня GCC под рукой нет, не могу посмотреть как он это все развернет.

Comment: На первый взгляд кажется, что `__TIME__` должно быть константным выражением, и всё должно компилироваться. Вы не могли бы показать сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: @VladD, ну ошибка о том и сигнализирует, что ожидалось константное выражение(С2057). Из нее вытекает и C2466 - нельзя выделить память для массива из 0 элементов.

Comment: А какая версия MSVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, является ли индекс `constexpr`.

В gcc `__TIME__` есть `constexpr`, поэтому код компилируется.

В 2013 MSVC `constexpr` не поддерживается, поэтому там `__TIME__` всего лишь `char const * const`. А этого, судя по всему, недостаточно.

Пруфы: http://ideone.com/MJQ8bB

Comment: Жаль. А для чего могло понадобиться запретить считать макроопределения __TIME__, __DATE__, __TIMESTAMP__ и некоторые другие не константно-определенными?

Comment: @0xFFh: Просто MSVC ещё не поддерживает `constexpr` вовсе. Если вы можете попробовать на 2015-ой студии, может там стронулось с места.

Comment: В 15, кажется, да - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/02/constexpr-complete-for-vs-2015-rtm-c-11-compiler-c-17-stl.aspx

Спасибо, в общем